# Computing the maximum value from local components

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js. Started from documentation and Laracasts.
I have a little problem. I want to "compute", which of my results are higher.

Example:

We have lists of Users. Each user can be granted some points. Total - 15 points for all users. I need to get top-rated users. And I don't know, where I need to define a special method. Try to initialize `computed` on Vue-instance - but I'm in stuck how I get child properties.

My vue-tag

```
<member v-for="member in members" :count=0 v-on:increment="incrementTotal" v-on:decrement="decrementTotal">@{{member.name}}</member>
```

Vue-instance:

```
var app = new Vue({
        props: ['counter'],
        el: '.vue2',
        data: {
            members: {!! $theme->members !!},
            total: 15
        },
        computed: {
            **// In stuck with this**
            topUsers() {
                //this.members.filter???
            }
        },
        components: {
            'member': member,
            'topRate': topRate,
        },
        methods: {
            incrementTotal: function () {
                this.total -= 1
            },
            decrementTotal: function () {
                this.total += 1
            }
        }
    })
```

Member component

```
var member = {
        props: ['name'],
        template: `
            <div class=''>
                <li>
                    <slot></slot>
                    <button type="button" v-on:click="decrement" class='btn'>-</button>
                    <span>@{{counter}}<span>
                    <button type="button" v-on:click="increment" class='btn'>+</button>
                    <input type='hidden' :name=name :value=counter>
                </li>
            </div>
        `,
        **// for each User personal counter**
        data: function() {
            return {
                counter: 0,
            }
        },
        **// increment/decrement user rating**
        methods: {
            increment: function () {
                if ( app.total !== 0 ){
                    this.counter += 1;
                    this.$emit('increment');
                }
            },
            decrement: function () {
                if (this.counter !== 0){
                    this.counter -= 1;
                    this.$emit('decrement');
                }
            }
        },
    }
```

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: is your vue instance inside your blade file or in it's own file not processed by blade?

Comment: whats the issue you are facing here, dont you have data in members?

Comment: Vue instance inside my blade file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties are functions that help you filter your data or compute other data based on your initial data.
For your case you have to return a filtered array of your members if you want for example 5 top members. The filter javascript function is basically a forEach that has a callback with current element in the array and inside that callback you have to specify a boolean operator so the filter function knows what to filter on.

Example

```
this.members.filter(function (member){
  return member.score>5;   
});
```

Or a shorten example with arrow functions

```
this.members.filter((member)=>member>5);
```

Here is a fiddle that I hope will clarify things out for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/501/

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your example:

```
computed: {
    **// In stuck with this**
    topUsers() {
        //this.members.filter???
    }
}
```

Your computed property is in fact a function that must return a value (the computed value). See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example

In your case, depending on your `$theme->members` data structure, that should be as simple as:

```
computed: {
    topUsers: function () {
        var topList = []
        for (var i = 0; i < this.members.length; i++) {
            // build your topList as you would like it to be
        }
        // return that built list
        return topList
    }
}
```

From there, anywhere in your Vue component, `this.topUsers` has the computed value of your `topList` variable. And its reactive: if `this.members` ever change, `this.topUsers` will be re-computed.